# How to share common build options or variables between multiple meson projects

Tags: build, meson-build

I am looking to migrate some SW repositories to Meson. With the current build system (make), a lot of common things like compiler flags are stored in one place and shared using e.g. git submodules. When updating compiler flags it thus only has to be done in one place not inside every single SW repository. I have not been able to find any resources that describe a similar approach when using meson. What is the recommended way of achieving the same behavior in meson ?